# How to add property to Django self.request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, middleware

I am using DRF and token based auth and need to frequently access a property called `request.user.organization_id` in my views. The organization_id is not stored in my user table, so I need to find a way to add it to the `request.user` object. I tried but failed at adding this property via middleware. How should I go about this?

Here is my middleware code:

```
class UserOrganizationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        primary_organization = OrganizationUser.objects.get(user=request.user).first()
        request.user.organization_id = primary_organization.organization
```

With my current middleware, request.user comes back as an anonymous user, even when I am logged in. My middleware is placed AFTER my authentication middleware in my settings file, but this still happens.

user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)  

    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email address'), unique=True)
```

Comment: Can you post the middleware code that you tried? Adding the model relations would help as well. Middleware is likely the right place to put it, but it's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: Why to the `request.user`, and not simply `request.organization`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It doesn't matter I suppose, but it seemed to make sense nested under the user, considering you log in as a user, not as an organization.

Comment: @SamDolan Done, although adding my organization model and through table would be a mess. I am abstracting from a third party package, django-organizations, for my organization model.

Comment: @ambe5960 I'd go in and and some break points to the auth middleware and to organization middleware and make sure they are both hit, and both hit in the correct order if you haven't done so already. The way you describe it and the code looks like it should work.

Comment: @SamDolan Thanks, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use middleware for that as far as i know the organisation has a relationship with the user model but you don't have the field because you specified a 'ForeignKey' of 'OneToOneField' in the Organisation model but you can access that organisation model object directly with ForeignKey or OneToOneField argument 'related_name' i will show you how

```
user model:

    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)  
        first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=50)
        last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=50)
        email = models.EmailField(_('Email address'), unique=True)

 organization model:

    class Organisation(models.Model)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="organisation")
        or 
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, realted_name="organisation")
        ....
```

add related name according to your model and after you can directly get the organisation model with reference of user like this

```
request.user.organisation
```